# Closing RadWindow from target url

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

This must be a stupid question, but I've been unable to find it.

I have an asp.net control that includes a RadWindowManager that has a child RadWindow.  The RadWindow has the property NavigateUrl set to an asp.net page.  I wish to have a Submit button that will do some server interaction and then close the RadWindow.  The page that is the target of the NavigateUrl property doesn't have a reference to the window, which is the source of the problem.

Control

```
<asp:Content>
    <RadWindowManager>
        <RadWindow NavigateUrl="PageLocation">
    </RadWindowManager>
</asp:Content>
```

Page

```
<asp:Content>
    <telerik:RadButton Text="Submit" OnClick="CloseRadWindow"/>
</asp:Content>
```

How can I have a page with a button that can control the closing of its container (the RadWindow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `self.close();` at the point where you want to close the `RadWindow`:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="Submit" OnClientClick="self.close();return false;" ... />
```

Comment: I have a follow up question that I've ran into about the difference in using the client event handlers or invoking from my code behind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757558/closing-radwindow-by-invoking-javascript-from-server